# object makes web method loop

Tags: c#, wcf

If I delete this `value = new { token = 1 }` or convert to `value = ""` webmethod works fine, otherwise method get triggered after return repeatedly.

Why this happens how to solve?

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "login/{username}/{password}")]
public Result Login(string username, string password)
{
     somecode..

     if (user != null && user.Password == password)
     {
         return new Result { statusCode = "200", message = "Success", value = new { token = 1 } }; 
     }
     else
     {
         return new Result { statusCode = "401", message = "Fail", value = "" };
     }
}

public class Result
{
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
}
```

this didn't work too;

```
return new Result { statusCode = "200", message = "Success", value = new Token { token = "some string" } }
```

Comment: Can you provide client side code ?

Comment: Its wcf web service, there is no client side. calling from browser

Comment: Where is user coming from? And nothing seems to be done with the username variable passed in. Is this correct?

Comment: I cleared some code to not confuse people which has nothing to do with problem.

Comment: so I guess I am gonna have to create DTO for every return :(

Comment: no It didn't work, I created DTO class for token still doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't have to be Token, It could be any DTO. thats why I left it object.

Comment: any work around to be able to use Result for many types without duplicating?

Comment: ofcourse It will solve but thats not what I am looking for. statusCode and message strongtype already working fine. what I am looking is something dynamic. could you say delete value property it will solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
    public Result Login(string username, string password)
    {
        int token=1;
        Result response = new Result();
        if (user != null && user.Password == password)
        {
            response.message = "Success";
            response.statusCode = "200";
            response.value = token;
        }
        else
        {
            response.message = "Fail";
            response.statusCode = "401";
            response.value = null;
        }
        return response;
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string statusCode { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public object value { get; set; }
    }
```